# python3 filter object with lambda fuctoin

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, lambda

```
garbled = "IXXX aXXmX aXXXnXoXXXXXtXhXeXXXXrX sXXXXeXcXXXrXeXt mXXeXsXXXsXaXXXXXXgXeX!XX"
m = list(filter(lambda x: x!='X', garbled))
print("".join(m))
```

I am another secret message!

but

```
type(m)
<class 'list'>
```

I am want answer in string So I followed,

```
garbled = "IXXX aXXmX aXXXnXoXXXXXtXhXeXXXXrX sXXXXeXcXXXrXeXt mXXeXsXXXsXaXXXXXXgXeX!XX"
m = str(filter(lambda x: x!='X', garbled))
m
'<filter object at 0x7f1d0afed710>'
```

I am newbie in python, need help on this. I am using python 3.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the return value of the [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) (`''.join(...)`) to `m`:

```
>>> garbled = "IXXX aXXmX aXXXnXoXXXXXtXhXeXXXXrX sXXXXeXcXXXrXeXt mXXeXsXXXsXaXXXXXXgXeX!XX"
>>> m = ''.join(filter(lambda x: x != 'X', garbled))
>>> m
'I am another secret message!'
>>> type(m)
<type 'str'>
```